# How to configure jax-rs related subsystem in jboss eap 7.0

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, jboss-eap-7, subsystem

I have a SOAP based web service that calls RESTFUL JAX-RS API of a third party using apache-wink client and is working fine on websphere 9.

But when I deploy the service on jboss EAP 7, deployment fails with error "org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000071: Managed bean with a parameterized bean class must be @Dependent: class org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.entity.csv.CsvDeserializerProvider\"}}""

After a bit of research I think that there are some jaxrs related config that I am missing on EAP server.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Simple+configuration+subsystems - they say that JAX-RS subsystem enables the deployment and functionality of jax-rs applications. But, its an empty tag, do we need to configure anything in this subsytem?

I want my service to successfully deploy and run on both webpshere and jboss.

Can anyone please help?